# How to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I would like to upgrade an Ubuntu system from 14.04 to 16.04. I ran the usually referenced command:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Which is strangely proposing to upgrade to 14.10:

[image]

If I then ask for the upgrade I get this error message:

[image]

How is it done exactly?

Comment: Even if set to "LTS" the command is still `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: The failed to fetch part that I missed is due to 14.10 no longer being available / supported.  Just thought that I would pass that on.  I don't think that 14.04 was meant to upgrade to 14.10 after this much time.=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

1. Edit the file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades .
2. Change the value of "Prompt" from "normal" to "lts".
3. Then try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.

See if that works.

Comment: Is says: `No new release found`.

Comment: Yes, the `-d` was missing. Please update your answer.

Comment: Oh!  That's odd!  The manual pages for the command says that the purpose of `-d` is to "Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible".  As 16.04 is already out, I thought it wasn't necessary.  Thanks for correcting it!

Comment: @Ray The actual upgrade of 16.04 does not get turned on until the first point release 16.04.1, which is around July, then it will work.  The `-d` option is to allow upgrading to the version now if you want and don't like waiting like me.  =)

Comment: @Terrance Ah!  Now that you mention it, I do remember that an LTS to LTS upgrade is meant to go to the first point release.  I think the reason is to let the impatient people (all of us!) to test it first.  :-)  Thanks for the reminder -- I guess I had typed `-d` when I upgraded a few weeks back and don't remember!

Answer (score -2):

> ### Failed to fetch
>
> Fetching the upgrade failed. **There may be a network problem**

The message may indicate that you need to check your connection or the upgrade servers. They may be down for the moment. But it actually means that is trying to upgrade to 14.10, instead of 15.10 or 16.04 LTS, which is EOL and therefore the packages are missing on the server. I would suggest to open a bug report against `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` or contact the [Release team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseTeam), as this shouldn't be the behavior of the upgrade manager.